# Переопределение virtual события

Tags: c#, события

Имеется такой пример:

```
public delegate void EventDelegate();

interface IInterface
{
    event EventDelegate MyEvent; // Абстрактное событие.
}

public class BaseClass : IInterface
{
    EventDelegate myEvent = null;

    public virtual event EventDelegate MyEvent // Виртуальное событие.
    {
        add { myEvent += value; }
        remove { myEvent -= value; }
    }

    public void InvokeEvent()
    {
        myEvent.Invoke();
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override event EventDelegate MyEvent // Переопределенное событие.
    {
        add
        {
            base.MyEvent += value;
            Console.WriteLine("К событию базового класса был прикреплен обработчик - {0}", value.Method.Name);
        }
        remove
        {
            base.MyEvent -= value;
            Console.WriteLine("От события базового класса был откреплен обработчик - {0}", value.Method.Name);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    // Методы обработчики события.

    static private void Handler1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Обработчик события 1");
    }

    static private void Handler2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Обработчик события 2");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        DerivedClass instance = new DerivedClass();

        // Присоединение обработчиков событий.
        instance.MyEvent += new EventDelegate(Handler1);
        instance.MyEvent += new EventDelegate(Handler2);

        // Метод который вызывает событие.
        instance.InvokeEvent();

        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));

        // Открепляем Handler2().
        instance.MyEvent -= new EventDelegate(Handler2);
        instance.InvokeEvent();

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

К данному примеру у меня три вопроса:

1. Переопределение события с помощью virtual - также как и метод InvokeEvent в данном примере   -   позволяет классам наследникам вызывать событие путем переопределения?
2. Если у меня одно событие - можно ли подписывать при переопределении это одно событие на разные обработчики переопределяя его в разные классы - т.е я имею ввиду, если я одно виртуальное событие переопределил в три разных класса и в каждом из них подписал на разные обработчики       событий, то если я затем создам экземпляр конкретного класса, то у меня сработают только обработчики из него , или из всех трех классов - т.к я переопределил одно событие в эти три класса?
3. также меня интересует эта строка:

   ```
   event EventDelegate MyEvent; // Абстрактное событие.
   ```

Как видно из комментария, автор курса говорит, что это абстрактное событие, но как я понимаю, это не тоже самое, что и с ключевым словом abstract? Я имею ввиду, что если по сущности это было бы тоже самое, что и  с ключевым словом abstract, то мы обязаны были бы его переопределить, на как видно, что мы этого не делаем. Так, что же подразумевается под понятием "абстрактное событие" ?

Comment: `myEvent.Invoke();` — неправильно. Правильно `myEvent?.Invoke();`

Answer (score 1):

1) Переопределение события — это по сути переопределение методов `add` и `remove`. То при этом подписывающиеся на event будут в реальности вызывать `add` производного класса.

Если производный класс, например, положит свой `EventDelegate myDerivedEvent`, а код базового класса вызовет `InvokeEvent` (который в вашем коде невиртуальный), то, очевидно, реальные подписчики будут проигнорированы.

2) Вопрос неясен.

> переопределении это одно событие на разные обработчики переопределяя его в разные классы

Событие не подписывается на обработчики. Наоборот, это обработчики подписываются на событие.

> переопределил в три разных класса

Неясно, как между собой связаны эти классы. Возможно, помог бы пример желаемого кода.

3) Автор (или переводчик) обходится нестрого с терминологией. В данном коде имеется в виду, что event в интерфейсе как бы не существует, а лишь декларирует, что класс, имплементирующий интерфейс, должен будет определить такой event.

Класс `BaseClass` в реальности таки определяет этот `event` строчкой

```
public virtual event EventDelegate MyEvent
```

(но не *пере*‌определяет его, иначе нужен был бы `override`).

Answer (score 1):

> 1) переопределение события с помощью virtual - также как и метод InvokeEvent в данном примере - позволяет классам наследникам вызывать событие путем переопределения?

Эти вещи не связаны между с собой. Генерация события (то есть вызов метода `event.Invoke(...)` или просто `event(...)`) , возможна только в том классе, где событие определено. В данном случае это класс `BaseClass`.

Если разработчик класса хочет разрешить генерацию события снаружи, он пишет **protected**, **internal** или **public** метод, вроде `InvokeEvent`. Тот, кто вызывает этот метод, генерирует событие. Обычно события всё-таки возникают в ходе работы каких-то методов класса `BaseClass` и не должны генерироваться снаружи, поэтому такие методы, как `InvokeEvent` чаще всего объявлены **private** или **protected**. Метод `protected InvokeEvent` может быть виртуальным, в этом случае классы наследники могут выполнять дополнительную работу, например, при генерации одного события генерировать также и другое, либо, наоборот, фильтровать часть событий:

```
private int eventCounter = 0;

protected override InvokeEvent()
{
    // позволяем генерировать только каждое чётное событие
    if (++eventCounter % 2 == 0)
        base.InvokeEvent();
}
```

Переопределение события позволяет наложить свою логику на методы `add` и `remove`, определённые в базовом классе. Например, ваш `BaseClass` может просто выполнять работу, а класс-наследник `DerivedClass` обеспечивает безопасность. И вы хотите, чтобы подписаться на событие мог только администратор:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override event EventDelegate MyEvent // Переопределенное событие.
    {
        add
        {
            if (!Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("admin"))
                throw new SecurityException("Hasta la vista, baby!");

            base.MyEvent += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            if (!Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("admin"))
                throw new SecurityException("Hasta la vista, baby!");

            base.MyEvent -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

И, ещё раз — резюме: **переопределения методов `add` и `remove` не предназначены для вызова события из классов-наследников**.

> 2) Если у меня одно событие - можно ли подписывать при переопределении это одно событие на разные обработчики переопределяя его в разные классы - т.е я имею ввиду, если я одно виртуальное событие переопределил в три разных класса и в каждом из них подписал на разные обработчики событий, то если я затем создам екземпляр конкретного класса, то у меня сработают только обработчики из него , или из всех трех классов - т.к я переопределил одно событие в эти три класса?

Вопрос задан запутано, но, если я правильно понял, то правильный вариант №1. Когда вы создаёте экземпляр конкретного класса-наследника, в нём действуют только методы базовых классов и его собственные. Методы братьев, племянников и т.д. — не действуют. Это касается и событий.

> 3) ... Так, что же подразумевается под понятием "абстрактное событие" ?

В данном случае автором допущена некоторая вольность, вызванная тем, что интерфейсы и абстрактные классы по сути очень близки. Скорее всего, автор когда-то писал на C++ где интерфейсы это разновидность абстрактных классов (чисто абстрактные классы). В .NET тем не менее разница существует, и, строго говоря, всё, что описано в интерфейсе, нельзя называть словом *абстрактный*.